# File Parse code gives me exceptions instead of a number and file writing code gives writes gibberish instead of a number

Tags: java, file-io

This code reads a notepad file
this notepad file has the number 10 on it
it returns a gibberish letter for some reason instead of 10
I think it is the ascii code but i do not know 
Also this code is modified from my programming teachers code so I do not take credit for it

```
/**
     *Goes in to the file and extracts a number.
     * @param fileName
     * @return an integer
     */
    static int getNumberFromFile(String fileName){
        int j = 599;
        try {
            File textFile = new File(fileName);
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(textFile);
            String input = sc.nextLine();
            j = Integer.parseInt(input);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        }
        return j;

    }
```

> throws this wierd exception Exception:
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10" and this code

```
/**
 * writes data for the ai to adapt its strategy
 *@param number is the number to write
 * @param fileName is the fileName
 */
public static void writeToFile(String fileName,int number) {

    BufferedWriter output = null;
    try {
        File aFile = new File(fileName);
        FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(aFile);
        output = new BufferedWriter(myWriter);
        output.write(number);
        output.newLine();
        output.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception:" + e);
        System.out.println("please Report this bug it doesnt understand");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

dont worry about some of the exception catch things those were for me to see if the exceptions are caught it just prints a (nonsense) message. and some of the stuff where a talk about an ai dont worry just need this code working I can post why the ai needs it but i dont think it is relevant

Comment: Presumably because your file doesn't have a number on the first line... (Don't get me wrong, it's horrible code... but if the file is okay, it should give the right value. I've just tried it and it worked for me.)

Comment: the file has 599 on the first line.

Comment: huh I changed j=599 (some arbitrary value) to j=0 and now it works

Comment: I suspect it has a trailing space or something then. Now would be a good time to learn to use a debugger, and look at exactly what's been read before you parse it. And no, changing the value of `j` would *not* make it work - I strongly suspect you've changed the content of the file.

Comment: Might have been the trailing space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line doesn't do what you expect:

```
output.write(number);
```

It's calling `write` on a `BufferedWriter`, so you should consult the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html)... at which point you find you're calling [this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write-int-).

> ```
> public void write(int c)
>       throws IOException
> ```
>
> Writes a single character.
>
> Overrides:
>       `write` in class `Writer`
>   Parameters:
>   `c` - `int` specifying a character to be written

And following the `write` link gives more details:

> Writes a single character. The character to be written is contained in the 16 low-order bits of the given integer value; the 16 high-order bits are ignored.
>   Subclasses that intend to support efficient single-character output should override this method.

So, you're writing the Unicode character U+000A - or would be if the value were really 10. I strongly suspect it's not though, as that would just be a line feed character.

If you're trying to write the decimal representation of the number though, you should turn it into a string first:

```
output.write(String.valueOf(number));
```

Comment: can you just let me know why it seems to be throwing an excpetion irregardless of the value